# Bootstrap UI Typeahead doesn't support two-way data binding

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead

Hello to all I read that this issue

```
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/274
```

is was closed... I've this jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/qq4gqn6t/12/

but when I change the model the label not change... Can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Any luck finding a solution for this? I'm struggling with this as well.

Comment: Hi @ChristofferKlemming, after a bit of work i made a directive... Hope that now work it! https://jsfiddle.net/qq4gqn6t/91/ Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Checkout if this [jsfiffle](https://jsfiddle.net/dse1pntc/), if that is your desired behavior?...

All I've done is:

```
<input ng-model="selected.descrizione" class="form-control">
```

replaced `state.descrizione` with `selected.descrizione`

Thing is, that `state` is not available outside `uib-typeahead` directive, but at the same time `selected` becomes handle that we can use.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand... In your fiddle you are change from   <input ng-model="selected.descrizione" class="form-control"> to <input ng-model="selected" class="form-control"> but this way not work....